# puntero dinamico en c++ no imprime la última línea de un array

Tags: c++, punteros

Cuando ejecuto el programa no me imprime la última línea por pantalla. Por ejemplo, si le digo que haga espacio para 3 `string` entonces solo me pregunta dos veces e imprime solo los 2 las dos primeras cadenas que yo digito.

Quiero saber por qué pasa esto y cual es la solucion para este problema.

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void numeroPalabras(string &palabras,int &num, string *&p)
{
    cout << ">>: ";
    cin >> num;

    p = new string[num];

    for (int i = 0; i < num ; i++)
    {
        getline(cin, p[i]);
    }
}

void presentar(string *&p, const int &num)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        cout << *p++ << endl;
}


int main()
{
    int num;
    string palabras;
    string *p;
    numeroPalabras(palabras, num, p);
    presentar(p,num);
    delete p;

    /* code */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ... y tampoco borras la memoria solicitada por `new` :O

Comment: pero igual el resultado no cambiaria

Comment: Lo se, pero es un fallo grave en C++. (sigo investigando tu pregunta).

Comment: es verdad muchas gracias, lo edite en este momento. gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void numeroPalabras(string &palabras,int &num, string *&p)
{
    cout << ">>: ";
    cin >> num; // <<---

    p = new string[num];

    for (int i = 0; i < num ; i++)
    {
        getline(cin, p[i]);
    }
}
```

Después de la línea que te marco en con el comentario en el buffer de entrada se queda almaceando un salto de línea. Eso hace que al llamar a `getline` por primera vez se lea una línea en blanco.

La solución es, en este caso, tan sencilla como limpiar el buffer de entrada:

```
cout << ">>: ";
cin >> num;
cin.ignore();
```

Otro error que has cometido, esta vez al liberar la memoria:

```
p = new string[num];
delete p;
```

Lo que se crea con `new[]` se debe liberar con `delete[]`. En caso contrario te arriesgas a dejar lagunas de memoria. Lo correcto es lo siguiente:

```
p = new string[num];
delete[] p;
```

Y como bonus adicional, pasar el puntero a `presentar` como una referencia a puntero es totalmente innecesario, accesorio y contraproducente (interiormente se gestionará como un puntero doble). Y lo mismo para tipos nativos... si el parámetro `num` es de solo lectura es preferible pasarlo por valor a pasarlo por referencia (el programa puede acabar usando punteros por detrás):

```
void presentar(string *p, const int num);
```

o incluso si te gusta añadir protecciones contra cambios:

```
void presentar(const string *p, const int num)
```

Comment: Como siempre, más rápido que yo.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster no siempre... creo que estamos al 50%

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta